# rails: getting most recent record within a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to get the most recent record if I have a loop. I'm getting an error with this syntax:

```
<% @user.pictures[0,5].order('created_at DESC').each_with_index do |s, i| %>
  <% link_to ... %>
<% end %>
```

My error is coming from

```
undefined method `order'
```

What syntax is correct to get the latest record?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limit:

```
<% @user.pictures.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).each_with_index do |s, i| %>
```

`@user.pictures[0, 5]` returns an array, and array does not have `order` method which is why you are getting that error.